# What can I do to help make my TensorFlow network overfit a large dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

The reason I am trying to overfit specifically, is because I am following the "Deep Learning with Python" by François Chollet's steps to designing a network. This is important as this is for my final project in my degree.

At this stage, I need to make a network large enough to overfit my data in order to determine a maximal capacity, an upper-bounds for the size of networks that I will optimise for.

However, as the title suggests, I am struggling to make my network overfit. Perhaps my approach is naïve, but let me explain my model:

I am using [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vinesmsuic/star-categorization-giants-and-dwarfs), to train a model to classify stars. There are two classes that a star must be classified by (into both of them): its spectral class (100 classes) and luminosity class (10 classes).
For example, our sun is a 'G2V', it's spectral class is 'G2' and it's luminosity class is 'V'.

To this end, I have built a double-headed network, it takes this input data:
[DataFrame containing input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqPW9.png)

It then splits into two parallel networks.

```
# Create our input layer:
input = keras.Input(shape=(3), name='observation_data')

# Build our spectral class
s_class_branch = layers.Dense(100000, activation='relu', name = 's_class_branch_dense_1')(input)
s_class_branch = layers.Dense(500, activation='relu', name = 's_class_branch_dense_2')(s_class_branch)

# Spectral class prediction
s_class_prediction = layers.Dense(100, 
                                  activation='softmax', 
                                  name='s_class_prediction')(s_class_branch)

# Build our luminosity class
l_class_branch = layers.Dense(100000, activation='relu', name = 'l_class_branch_dense_1')(input)
l_class_branch = layers.Dense(500, activation='relu', name = 'l_class_branch_dense_2')(l_class_branch)

# Luminosity class prediction
l_class_prediction = layers.Dense(10, 
                                  activation='softmax', 
                                  name='l_class_prediction')(l_class_branch)

# Now we instantiate our model using the layer setup above
scaled_model = Model(input, [s_class_prediction, l_class_prediction])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.004)

scaled_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'s_class_prediction':'categorical_crossentropy',
                    'l_class_prediction':'categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics=['accuracy'])

logdir = os.path.join("logs", "2raw100k")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)

scaled_model.fit(
    input_data,{
        's_class_prediction':spectral_targets,
        'l_class_prediction':luminosity_targets
        },
    epochs=20, 
    batch_size=1000,
    validation_split=0.0,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

In the code above you can see me attempting a model with two hidden layers in both branches, one layer with a shape of 100 000, following into another layer with 500, before going to the output layer. The training targets are one-hot encoded, so there is one node for every class.

I have tried a wide range of sizes with one to four hidden layers, ranging from a shape of 500 to 100 000, only stopping because I ran out of RAM. I have only used dense layers, with the exception of trying a normalisation layer to no affect.

[Graph of losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3T47.png)

They will all happily train and slowly lower the loss, but they never seem to overfit. I have run networks out to 100 epochs and they still will not overfit.

What can I do to make my network fit the data better? I am fairly new to machine learning, having only been doing this for a year now, so I am sure there is something that I am missing. I really appreciate any help and would be happy to provide the logs shown in the graph.

Comment: From the graph, you have provided it is quite difficult to say that your model is not overfitting. Overfitting is characterized by the differences in performance between the training and validation (or test) set. I think comparing your training performance with validation performance will paint a clearer picture.

Comment: @Aryagm that's a good suggestion! I retrained the network above with validation data and the results are [interesting](https://imgur.com/a/otjeeWQ). It clearly begins to overfit, unlike compared with the training set, but then its loss begins to drop again. I'm not too sure what to make of this, to me it looks like it isn't overfitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more training I think I have this answered. Basically, the network did not have adequate capacity and needed more layers. I had tried more layers earlier but because I was not comparing it to validation data the overfitting was not apparent!

The proof is in the pudding:

[image]

So thank you to @Aryagm for their comment, because that let me work it out. As you can see, the validation data (grey and blue) clearly overfits, while the training data (green and orange) does not show it.

If anything, this goes to show why a separate validation set is **so important** and I am a fool for not having used it in the first place! Lesson learned.